# Как узнать версию Python в Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Как посмотреть версию *Python* в терминале *Linux*?

Comment: python --version

Comment: есть оригинальнее способ. Если включено автодополнение (а это редко бывает, если оно выключено), то пишем python и дважды нажимаем tab. Дальше будет все понятно:)

Comment: @KoVadim наверное для тех кто в танке надо уточнить, что после python надо без пробела сразу жать на tab ;)

Comment: Спасибо уже перешёл исключительно на Windows 10. Angular.js

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Версия интерпретатора *Python* выводится в терминале командой

```
python --version
```

Однако, надо иметь в виду, что в современных дистрибутивах *Ubuntu* (и не только) присутствуют сразу две версии интерпретатора - *Python 2* и *Python 3*. Указанная выше команда вызовет *Python 2*. Чтобы вызвать *Python 3*, команда должна быть другой:

```
python3 --version
```

Comment: как обновить базовую версию Python: Operating systems Linux ubuntu, и тогда установится Gimp!